# Collapsing toolbar blur image when collapsed

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I need some help with my toolbar.

Right now I use a collapsing toolbar with image which collapses when I scroll up.
I know I can use contentScrim to make the Toolbar transparent and therefore see the image as "toolbar background".

However, I want the image to blur(/fade) when the toolbar is collapsed.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the image content dynamic or not ?

Comment: the image is the result of somekind of search request so yes it is dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this library. ([RealTimeBlurView](https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView))
For the blur effect, just put the imageview behind the blurview.
To achieve what you want just change blurview's alpha when the app bar is scrolled.

```
appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int verticalOffset) {
        float offsetAlpha = (appBarLayout.getY() / appbar.getTotalScrollRange());
        blurView.setAlpha( 1 - (offsetAlpha * -1));
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

[FastBlur](https://github.com/paveldudka/blurring/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/paveldudka/util/FastBlur.java)
Here's another [benchmarking project](https://github.com/patrickfav/BlurTestAndroid) to showcase all the possible blurring methods in android.
 Just get the fastest algorithm from the demo and use it in your project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but did you know any pure java solution? I just need the blur effect when the Toolbar is completly collapsed

Comment: Thank you again! i've got a typo :/ I meant pure Android/Google lib iam not such a fan of third party lib. Would nice if you could provide another example anyway you deserved that answer accepted !

Comment: That's not a library. FastBlur is pure java class. Just put it in your project and pass the right parameters.

Comment: I added other blurring solutions, you can check.