# Blur and Unblur images in collapsing Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-blur-effect

In my `CountryImageInfo.java` I have a collapsing toolbar with an image inside.
This is what it looks like:

[image]

I want to know how to blur the image as it collapses and how to unblur has it comes down again. Similar to the notification bar of iOS, I don't know if you're familiarized with it... **I've seen questions similar to this but** the difference was, some were asking how to blur when it is collapsed (not what I'm asking. I'm asking as it collapses. A gradual blur)...

**This is my XML**, by the way, everything is wrapped up in a `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparainfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarDivider">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbarinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCountryInfoFoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCountryInfoEscuro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_pais_info"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbaridinfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNomePaisInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparainfo"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Update:**

Duplicate the image isn't really what I want because these images are a little big so, is there another approach besides duplicate the images?
I searched for some libraries but I couldn't find anything that could fit my needs... I can blue all the image, is there a way to set a listener to start blurring when the user drags the collapsing bar up? Please, help, I've tried lots of things!

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980413/9734616). It might help you

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi It actually doesn't because the person who asked the question wanted just the blur when the image is collapsed, not gradually ahah

Comment: Yes but if you look at the accepted answer, you'll find that the person has added OnOffsetChangedListener on the appbar which is providing the the detail of how much offset has been changed according to which he has set the alpha to the blurView. So eventually that will help you.

Comment: If you still have problem than let us know

Comment: I tried to do what the answer said but it gives me this error when I try to run my app:
`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libRSSupport.so'`

Comment: Okay than let's find some other solution. :)

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi Thanks for the help. I'll keep trying too

Comment: I have achieved this with the suggested answer only. I did some changes to it. Posting them in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [RealtimeBlurView](https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView). To use this do make changes in the `build.gradle` of your app module.

Add dependencies in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.2'
}
android {
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'                 // Use 23.0.3 or higher
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true    // Enable RS support
    }
}
```

> Add proguard rules if necessary:
>
> -keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }

Then add following view in your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
<com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
            android:id="@+id/blurView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:realtimeBlurRadius="20dp"
            app:realtimeOverlayColor="#8000" />
```

And in your activity add following code.

```
final AppBarLayout appBar = findViewById(R.id.testeparainfo);
final RealtimeBlurView blurView = findViewById(R.id.blurView);
blurView.setAlpha(1F);
appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int verticalOffset) {
        float offsetAlpha = (appBarLayout.getY() / appBar.getTotalScrollRange());
        blurView.setAlpha(offsetAlpha * -1);
    }
});
```

Took help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980413/9734616)

Comment: I'll try it! But just one thing, how do I add `proguard rules`? Where do I install it?

Comment: If you don't have proguard till now than it's not necessary

Comment: It still gives me this error:
`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libRSSupport.so'`

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file. So that i can look into it, and provide proper information

Comment: The error you are getting is possibly because the RealTimeBlurView is conflicting with some other  lib. Tracking that

Comment: I'll track it too. The heads think better than one ahah

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Android Blurry Library](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry)

```
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
    double percentage = (double) Math.abs(verticalOffset) / collapsingToolbar.getHeight();
    if (percentage > 0.8) {
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Collapsed");
    } else {
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Expanded");
    }

Blurry.with(context)
  .radius(10 * percentage)
  .sampling(8)
  .color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0))
  .async()
  .animate(500)
  .onto(blurryImage); // imgCountryInfoEscuro
}
```

Comment: The "rootView" is what?

Comment: This solution did not help me

Comment: @AndréSilva rootView is to be `blurryImage // imgCountryInfoEscuro` check my answer update, you can also use `async` or without.
`